# Altering custom template from code

Tags: theming, 9

How can I programmatically remove blocks and other elements from a single custom template ?

In my custom modle I have defined a route to a controller which then loads a template which is also contained within the same module.
I am successfully loading data from the controller into the template.

My issue is that the template inherits blocks and menu from the active theme which I need to remove but only in the modules template. For examples, the search and primary naviagation blocks are not supposed to display.

I had implemented :

```
function mymodule_export_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  unset($variables['page']['header']['searchform']);
  unset($variables['page']['menu_primary']);
}
```

But I later realised the seach and navigation blocks were removed not just in the module template but from every page on the site.

I also search for something like `hook_page_alter` that could not find anything appropriate for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing themes and templates.

A **theme** is a set of files that control the display of your site via the use of template files, CSS and Javascript (mostly that, there is more if you dig).

A **template file** is just one of those files in a theme.

So the reason that the logic in your `hook_preprocess_page` affects every page, is that you apply those modifications unconditionally. Those preprocess hooks (when defined in a module) are applied to the active theme for any page request, whichever theme is used.

It's a bit difficult to suggest a specific solution in your case without seeing further code, e.g. from your controller, but you can try something along these lines (pseudo-code):

```
function mymodule_export_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'route.to.controller') {
    unset($variables['page']['header']['searchform']);
    unset($variables['page']['menu_primary']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Berliner. I got too invested in a hook oriented solution and forgot all about the humble if-statement